# Using SQLXMLBulkload via Java

Tags: java, .net, sql-server, bulk-load

Is it possible to use the `SQLXMLBulkload` component of SQL Server using Java? I am using SQL Server 2005 database for my Java EE application.

If not then is there any similar API for Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately I found out that there is no nice way of doing it. Persisting XML to Relation database is still a challenge.
For my project I end up marshaling XML to Java and then persisted Java objects to DB with the help of Hiberante:

 I understand that performance is a big concern with this approach but I didn't hit any performance issue yet. Plus this approach give me flexibility for example saving attribute values in separate columns etc.